# Rails use ! (exclamation point) in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, routes

In my application, I would like to create static pages namespaced under the '!' (exclamation point). For example:

```
/!/about
/!/faq
```

Currently, I have it functional using the prefix `pages` in my `routes.rb` file:

```
# config/routes.rb
get 'pages(/:action)' => 'pages', :as => :page
```

This works great, and generates the correct URLs, etc. However, if I replace `pages` with `!`, the routes fail:

```
# config/routes.rb
get '!(/:action)'...
```

Here's the output of `rake routes`:

```
pages GET     /!(.:format)             {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"index"}
page GET      /!/:action(.:format)     {:controller=>"pages"}
```

As you can see, Rails is generating the routes. However, when I try to use any of those named routes in my views, I get a routing error:

```
No route matches {:controller => "pages", :action => "about"}
```

Ironically, If I use any other symbol (like `@`) the routes work as expected. Why can't I use an `!` exclamation point in my routes :(. Should I be filing an issue on github?

P.S. it also fails if I specify the route manually `{:controller => :pages, :action => :about}` with the same error.

P.S.S the routes actually work if visited directly (`/!/about`) renders the correct page. The URL helpers just won't let it actually create the link :(

Comment: Thought i had an answer, but then i ran into the same issue. Removing the exclamation mark allows the home_path() method to work. Otherwise it doesn't recognize it. Might be a good idea to file a bug, unless someone else can provide an answer. For now to solve your issue, I suggest just using an HTML link for now at least.

Comment: Phew. At least I know I'm not crazy. I'd really prefer not to resort to (gasp) HTML links (especially since I use nice and pretty HAML). Right now I'm just using the `@` sign instead :/. I'll wait 2 days, open a bounty, and then file an issue. I'd rather not burden the Core team unless I'm absolutely sure.

Comment: Yeah, i think that's a good idea. Another thing you could do is use the link to, and concatenate the exclamation mark infront. Though it's not a whole lot prettier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from [RFC3986 Uniform Resource Identifier: Generic Syntax](http://labs.apache.org/webarch/uri/rfc/rfc3986.html#reserved)

```
2.2 Reserved Characters

  reserved    = gen-delims / sub-delims

  gen-delims  = ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"

  sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
              / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

As such, you shouldn't include `!` in your paths.

You may have seen google's `#!` syntax for making ajax web apps crawlable by search engines.

eg. https://twitter.com/#!/exampleUser

But in this case, it's a trick;

The path is just "/", and the rest is regarded as the "anchor" or "hash"

```
host = "twitter.com"
path = "/"
hash = "#!/exampleUser"
```

Comment: I'm aware of hash-bangs and their use. However, Rails still let's me use :, @, +, -, _, ... in my routes. It won't let me use a `!` though.